# How does C++ zero initialize static vaiables in constant time

Tags: c++, static, initialization

This C++ code zero initializes 200M variable in about 2 ms in my computer, which is far from linear time. How is C++ able to do it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

static char arr[200000000];

int main ()
{
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    std::cout << (int)arr[rand() % 200000000];
}
```

Comment: How ware you timing the 2 ms? The initialization will normally happen before `main` is entered, as the code is loaded (which is generally pretty difficult to time).

Comment: Also, how do you know that "it's far from linear time"? That's not how algorithmic analysis works.

Comment: @H2CO3 dunno what you mean with your first comment ;)

Comment: @nijansen Oh, sorry, I wanted to write "wtf are all those edits on the question" :P

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss

Comment: The OS should be able to allocate large pages of zeros very quickly (as long as you don't write to them).

Comment: You only provide one point (X elements in Y time). How come you conclude from it that the time is "not linear"? Also, why do you expect it to be "linear"?

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't do it in zero time. But you'll probably find it hard to measure the time in your application, since the zero-initialization happens "before `main`" - in particular, most OS's support zero-initialization specifically by assigning all memory the value zero before the OS gives it to the application, so there is "nothing to be done" in the application code to set it to zero. But in an OS that doesn't do that, part of the code that runs before `main` is a bit that sets all global variables (that aren't initialized) to zero. And unless you have HUGE amounts of global data, it does that pretty quickly. Modern processors can fill memory at 5GB/s+. Given that your array is only 200MB, it would take about 0.04s to fill that.